# How to check button is clicked in vba

Tags: excel, vba, button, userform

i want to check if the button in my userform is clicked, may i know how do i do that ? My ultimate aim is to get the number of times the button is clicked. It is something along the codes, I typed. Thank you for your help.

```
 If CommandButton1_Click = True Then 
 x = x + 1 
 End If
```

Comment: All buttons are by default **not** clicked. When you click a button the attached macro will start and then the button will return to its default position of **not** being pressed / clicked. These button will only have the `clicked` status for less than a second (to start the attached macro). Afterwards they have immediately the not-clicked-state again. Maybe you are looking for another control such as a checkbox or an option button? These can have other states and they can keep them for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you click a button the Button_Click() sub is called. There you could use a cell or a global variable (depends on what you want to do) to increment each time that function is called.

For example you could do that:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Module1.x = Module1.x + 1
End Sub
```

and on Module1 you have:

```
Option Explicit

Public x As Integer
```

edit1:

I have added another button and diplay a messagebox when it is clicked with the number of times the first button (variable x) is clicked:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    MsgBox Module1.x
End Sub
```

Your project should look like that with a form:

[image]

Comment: may i ask what is the differences when i do my code on the worksheet and on the module ?

Comment: No difference! It depends only where you have your buttons. If you have them like me in a sheet then you have to put the button_click code in that sheet in the vba editor.

Comment: I changed the picture to give you an idea how it would look like with the userform! It does the same thing! Keep in mind that the variable x will startover every time you restart the workbook (doesn't save the value)